# Why does Length not work on a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

I am trying to check the length of string, but I get `unrecognized selector` when the code is executed and hits the `IF` statement.

***THE VALUE IN THE DICTIONARY IS A STRING.***

```
NSString * checkString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"];
    NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)[checkString length]);

if([checkString length]  > 0){

}
```

ERROR From console:

> length: 0
>   [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

***For simplicity:***

```
 NSString * checkString = @"my string"; //[myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"];
    NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)[checkString length]);

    if([checkString length] > 0){
}
```

> length: 9
>   [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

Why?

Comment: try to cast  [myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"] to NSString or use string withFormat

Comment: According to the error, it's a `NSNumber` and not a `NSString` It's not because you casted it as a `NSString` that it's a `NSString`. But what's weird is that it logs correctly "length: %lu", so the issue is just after it, what's the code that cause the crash? If you do `[[myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` is returns TRUE?

Comment: That output doesn't make sense if that is your real code.  Is that actually the real code you are running copy-pasted into your question?  You're sure both the NSLog and the if statement are referring to the same variable?

Comment: ** *THE VALUE IN THE DICTIONARY IS NOT A STRING, BUT A NUMBER* ** ;-) Sorry, could not resist. Don't argue with the RTE. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The error says that your instance is not a `NSString` but a `NSNumber`. That's probably because you stored a `NSNumber` in `[myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"]`.

Try to put `[yourValueThatYouThinkItsAString stringValue]` in the place where you store this value.

I tried your code and I'm not getting error with it (with @"my string" value).

What you can try :

```
NSString *checkString = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"] stringValue];
NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)[checkString length]);

if([checkString length]  > 0){

}
```

PS : in your NSLog() you've got a additional argument, remove it.

Comment: No its not an NSNumber, it is a string in the dictionary.

Comment: Check the revised question.

Comment: Check again, I don't see where it comes from if it's not here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `length` is not working on `NSString*` is that it's not `NSString*`. Despite the cast, which Objective-C cannot verify, the object in your dictionary is `NSNumber*`, not `NSString*`. That is why the code compiles, but fails to run.

`[myDictionary objectForKey:@"somekey"]` call returns `id`, a generic object reference. That is why Objective-C must trust you when you perform a cast to `NSString*` that the object at `"somekey"` is actually a string.

It does not fail in `NSLog` because you made a mistake that prevents the length from being evaluated. Change `NSLog` to see it fail:

```
NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)[checkString length]);
```

If you have XCode 7 or newer, you can use lightweight generics to help Objective-C with type checking. You can specify object types for keys and values in your dictionary, so that the compiler could catch invalid casts for you:

```
NSDictionary<NSString*,NSString*> *myDictionary = ...
```

Comment: Then why does it NSLog the 0 but fails on IF? The value in dictionary is a string.

Comment: Please check the revised question.

Comment: @Firemarble Please check the revised answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please look at the revised question under For Simplicity.

Comment: @Firemarble Yes, that's exactly where I looked. Change `NSLog(@"length: %lu", checkString, (unsigned long)[checkString length]);` to `NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)[checkString length]);` to see the crash in `NSLog`, as expected.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That was a copy and paste error where i was also outputting the string. That doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Firemarble When I change it like that I do not get an error, which is exactly what I expect to happen.